# How to extract a value from a specific row found by using .loc to return to a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been able to narrow down the results from the rather large dataframe I need to a specific row, however I need to return the value held inside that row to be returned into a variable as an integer to be able to continue developing my small inflation calculator program.

So far the code listed below is as far as I've gotten, I was able to narrow it down but hit a roadblock and haven't tried anything else.

```
import datetime
import bls
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
bls.api.set_api_key('57be506cc77d48f2b61bac4b80058fd8')
inflation_and_prices = bls.get_series('CUSR0000SA0', 2000,)
inf=pd.DataFrame(inflation_and_prices)

print(inf.loc['2011-02',:])
#result is
CUSR0000SA0    221.898
Name: 2011-02, dtype: float64
```

I want the listed value at that index value to be returned and stored into a variable. But so far I have been unable to form any ideas about how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you mean:

```
var = inf.loc['2011-02',:].item()
```

That would store the value (`221.898`) into a variable.

And:

```
print(var)
```

Gives you:

```
221.898
```